# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in reactjs even when using it on array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to render data which is comming from nodejs api  I am using redux for state management.
The problem is When i try to map over the data it gives me error saying this.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
>
> This is my code     /home.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getArticle} from '../../redux/actions/article';


class Home extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getArticle();
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.article.article);
        

        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.article.article.data.map(val => console.log(val)) }}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   article: state.article
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getArticle})(Home);
```

> this is the log when i run `this.props.article.article`

[image: log image]

Comment: do you set the default value for `article` in Redux?

Comment: No there is no default value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you didn't set any default value for `article` in redux, Because of which when your component renders first, `article` is empty and that's why map throws an error.

By doing this,  you are ensuring that  `this.props.article.article.data` is defined or not. if that is defined then only `this.props.article.article.data.map(val => console.log(val))` your `map()` executes and console.log the value, but if that is not defined it simply do nothing.
Can you please try using this:

```
 return (
            <div>
                {this.props.article.article.data && this.props.article.article.data.map(val => console.log(val)) }}
            </div>
        );
```

Comment: This worked. can you please explain about this  a little ?

Comment: Here, you are dispatching an action in componentDidMount. After this lifecycle render will get called. During first render there is no any data in props.article.  That's why we need to apply check here for the props.article.data. If it exists, then only we will **map** over it.

Answer (score 1):

Its because, the component is trying to render before the network call is done.

Before we map through, we check id the article data is available. Try this to out:

```
return (
            <div>
                {this.props.article.article.data? this.props.article.article.data.map(val => console.log(val)):'Loading' }
           </div>
        );
```